# Using the same VPC image on multiple workstations

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I haven't used an VMs before so brand new to the party. I'm running Win7 off an honest to goodness MSDN license so OS licensing is not an issue.

I'd like to think that I could create a VPC image on a USB/eSATA hard drive and move that drive from one Win7-based workstation/laptop to another and I'd have the same services/desktop/computing environment at all of them.

I'm a developer working against the IIS7/SQL08 stack with VS10 so i'm working with apps and services as deeply embedded with the OS as you can get.

Should I expect to be able to pull this off?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work fine.   I have a development image that I run under VirtualBox on multiple machines with no problem.   It's loaded on a 16Gb flash drive.

One tip:  It can be really annoying to use a flash drive between machines when a consistent drive letter isn't maintained on each machine.   To solve this problem, use Disk Manager to assign your flash drive to A or B on each machine that you use.  These drive letters are always reserved, so no USB devices will use them unless explicitly assigned.